# Contract Testing DSL wrong behaviour / bug

Tags: kotlin, corda

I'm writing a Contract Test for my CorDapp but I'm stuck at a point because it isn't behaving as it should.

This is the contract code (only the relevant part is presented)

```
when (command.value ) {
        is LoanCommands.Issue -> requireThat {
            "No Inputs should be consumed when issuing a Loan" using ( tx.inputs.isEmpty())
            "Only a single output must be created when issugin a Loan" using (tx.outputs.size == 1)
            "Outputs must not be empty" using (tx.outputs.isNotEmpty())
```

Then this is the test that I'm running

```
    @Test
fun issueTransactionMustHaveOneOutputOfTypeLoanContract() {

    ledger {
        transaction {
            command(loanState.issuer.owningKey) { LoanContract.LoanCommands.Issue() }
            timeWindow(ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), time, zoneId).toInstant())

            this `fails with` "Outputs must not be empty"
        }
        transaction {
            command(loanState.issuer.owningKey) { LoanContract.LoanCommands.Issue() }
            timeWindow(ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), time, zoneId).toInstant())
            output { loanState } // Two outputs fails.
            output { dummyState}
            this `fails with` "Only a single output must be created when issugin a Loan"
        }

        transaction {
            command(loanState.issuer.owningKey) { LoanContract.LoanCommands.Issue() }
            output { loanState } // One output passes.
            timeWindow(ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), time, zoneId).toInstant())
            this.verifies()
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the second transaction fails correctly (when I remove the first), but the first give me this error

```
2017-08-14 12:32:15,250 main WARN Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream

java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception but didn't get one

at net.corda.testing.Verifies$DefaultImpls.failsWith(LedgerDSLInterpreter.kt:62)
at net.corda.testing.TransactionDSLInterpreter$DefaultImpls.failsWith(TransactionDSLInterpreter.kt)
at net.corda.testing.TestTransactionDSLInterpreter.failsWith(TestDSL.kt:89)
at net.corda.testing.Verifies$DefaultImpls.fails with(LedgerDSLInterpreter.kt:76)
at net.corda.testing.TransactionDSLInterpreter$DefaultImpls.fails with(TransactionDSLInterpreter.kt)
at net.corda.testing.TestTransactionDSLInterpreter.fails with(TestDSL.kt:89)
at net.corda.testing.TransactionDSL.fails with(TransactionDSLInterpreter.kt)
at com.template.contractTests.LoanContractIssueTest$issueTransactionMustHaveOneOutputOfTypeLoanContract$1$1.invoke(LoanContractIssueTest.kt:123)
at com.template.contractTests.
```

Why it isn't raising an exception? It looks like the `tx.outputs.isNotEmpty()` is not working.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: you should test each transaction separately, there is an example here: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-tutorial/blob/master/kotlin-source/src/test/kotlin/com/example/contract/IOUContractTests.kt

Comment: I will try, but as I read here https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-M14.0/tutorial-test-dsl.html you can chain transactions in a test, if not with a slightly complex contract you would write too many redundant code

Comment: chain transactions in a test will change the states.

Comment: Ok I will try, but the problem is in the first transaction, what should change from my code? Creating a new empty function with only that transaction won't change much I guess, but w/e let me see

Comment: Tried right now, creating a new empty test only for that transaction still get me the same error

Comment: all of the 3 transaction tests are failed?

Comment: The second one fails "correctly" and the third one verifies, the problem is in the first one that doesn't fail with the error provide but verify so the compiler says it should verify and throw an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the transaction in the first test does not contain any inputs or outputs. For a transaction to be valid, it must be accepted by the contracts of all the inputs and outputs. Since you have no inputs or outputs, the transaction is always valid.

This is not an issue when you have two outputs, as the `verify` function is run due to the presence of the two outputs in that case.

Comment: Ok, so let's say that it doens't have sense to test a transaction without inputs and outputs right?

Comment: Yes - I can't imagine a situation where it would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Good question - from your code I don't see the issue. However, note that your rules seem overlapping. You test that there is exactly one output, and then after that, that there are >0 outputs. The second test can be removed, it will never catch anything that the first doesn't.

Comment: Yeah I know, originally there were only the first two. I added the third one with a false hope that it would have changed something ahah

Comment: Is there any difference between writing input, output, command, timeWindow etc in different order? Maybe there is a preferred order like input -> issue command -> output -> timeStamp ?